# Stress analysis for a wall mounted table/desk

Tags: wood, walls, furniture, mounting, desk

I need to build a wall mounted table/desk. I've done my calculation (full stress analysis) and I've moved all forces to the mounting points but now I'm stuck because I don't know how much would those screws handle.

Well I do know how much would the screw handle but I don't know how much would the wall actually handle, i.e., the structure could fail because the screw may break the wall (just a couple of centimeters around it) then it all fails.

Another good point is that I've seen weak structures (in my POV) that handle so much weight (more than what I'm going to do) with fewer mounting points but I'm too afraid that my first table falls off.

Any advice? Any possible close structure out there that I could find useful that have really good factor of safety (around 3-4)?

About the design: it's simple rectangle of 150cm x 50cm and could be mounted with 3-5 screws to a corner.

Comment: I used shelfTrack and it works great. I added more shelves too so it gives me great storage space. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-ShelfTrack-84-in-Standard-Bracket-2812/100194576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securely screw your mounting hardware into something structural, and it's unlikely you'll "break the wall" unless you're planning on piling thousands of kilograms on your table.

If your structure is made of wood, make sure you screw into the framing members with long screws. Don't just screw into the drywall or plaster, which are not capable of bearing much of a load. If your structure is masonry-based, then use masonry-rated screws. They won't come out and they certainly won't break the wall.